# Change deploy folder of Tomcat 7

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, ubuntu-server

I need to deploy a .war project in the folder /home/username/web (for instance), but i can't solve this.

Apache is pointing to this folder. But the only thing that I see is the .war that I copy there.

I think that the problem is that Tomcat is pointing to webapp folder instead mine. Can I change that? And how?

Thanks!

#### EDITED

I edit server.xml file to add a host with the appBase attribute to /home/username/web.
But now I get the error that the directory does nos exist or is not a directory.
I think that is a permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this by updating the appBase attribute:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html